# How to dump the XML layout of the foreground Android activity (without uiautomator)?

Tags: android, xml, layout, adb, android-uiautomator

I've been using `adb shell uiautomator dump` and this works *some* of the time for *some* apps on my Pixel 2 device. When it decides to not work, I get this error message:

**ERROR: could not get idle state.**

I've read online that this is supposedly due to the UI not staying still while executing the dump, but even after letting apps idle for several minutes I still see that error. Even tried rebooting and rerooting the device. Is there a more reliable solution for this, preferably a native one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CulebraTester2](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public).
It does not use `uiautomator` so you may not be affected by its limitation, which needs some idle time to be able to get the dump, and this doesn't happen when an animation is constantly being updated.

There are prebuilt APKs available at [Github Actions](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/commit/9855bd122f811e8c6bf47f0dea2c5af19ab5a711/checks?check_suite_id=384131120) (see Artifacts).

1. Install both APKs
2. Start server: [./culebratester2](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/culebratester2) start-server
3. Dump hierarchy: [./dump-window-hierarchy](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/dump-window-hierarchy) XML

The default format for the dump is `JSON` that's why you should specify `XML` in the command line if this is what you want.